# Перебрать все возможные варианты строки с буквами в разных регистрах

Tags: php

Впал в ступор от, вроде бы, простой задачки.

Дана строка, к примеру, "abc". Требуется поменять каждой букве регистр и собрать все уникальные варианты:

```
abc
aBc
abC
Abc
ABc
ABC
aBC
AbC
```

Было бы замечательно, если бы объяснили алгоритм перебора и изменения регистра (само решение, конечно, тоже не помешает)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый символ может находиться в двух состояниях, так что всего существует 2^N вариантов, где N - длина строки.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/TUGWa3)

```
function traverse($S, $idx) {
  if ($idx ==  strlen($S)) {
        print_r($S);
        return;
  }
  traverse($S, $idx + 1);
  traverse(substr_replace($S, strtoupper($S[$idx]), $idx, 1), $idx + 1);
  return;
}

traverse("abc", 0);

>>abcabCaBcaBCAbcAbCABcABC
```

Возможно также нерекурсивное решение, как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955897/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-php/955921#955921)

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение со степенью! Это для меня вообще самое непонятное было (как заранее посчитать количество комбинаций)

Comment: Кстати, в строке могут быть ещё быть и цифры - тогда без вызова is_numeric появятся дубли :)

Comment: @Robert Это (`is_numeric`) можно сделать перед вторым рекурсивным вызовом

Comment: спасибо, да с этим-то я сразу разобрался. Там правда скорее стоит проверять на буквы (ctype_alpha), потому что в строке могут быть ещё и другие символы (дефисы, точки, арифметические знаки и что угодно)

Answer (score 4):

Вот пример решения:

```
<?php
function translate($n, $lengthOfBitsMask, $str)
{
    $res = "";
    for ($i = $lengthOfBitsMask - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $chr = mb_strtolower(mb_substr($str, $lengthOfBitsMask - $i -1, 1));
        if ($n & pow(2, $i)) {
            $chr = mb_strtoupper($chr);
        }
        $res .= $chr;
    }
    return $res;
}

$str = "abc";
$lengthOfBitsMask = mb_strlen($str);

echo "Dec  | Bin  | foobar\n--------------------\n";
for ($n = 0; $n < pow(2, $lengthOfBitsMask); $n++) {
    echo sprintf("%04d | %0" . $lengthOfBitsMask . "b", $n, $n) . " | " . translate($n, $lengthOfBitsMask, $str) . "\n";
}
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8d886060ae443e97aa6701f0f64efb10b741837)

Имеем на вход строку. Нужно взять ее длину, которая будет использоваться как длина битовой маски, для получения максимального значения числа (*n*) с использованием двоичного счисления.

Перебираем последовательно все числа в диапозоне (*0*)  . . (*n - 1*) и выводим на консоль.

При выводе на консоль числа, делаем трансляцию вывода из двоичного формата, с использованием *0* и *1*, в новый, специфичный формат, в котором используется входная строка. Из входной строки берутся и преобразовываются знаки, с заданным смещением (по номеру выводимого бита): *0* транслируется в знак в нижнем регистре, а *1* - в верхнем.

Comment: Хорошая  идея со спецалфавитом. Может быть, сразу `{"abc","ABC"}` создать и выбирать символ из строки с нужным индексом?

Comment: Чуть сложновато для восприятия утром, но спасибо :) Сейчас буду потихоньку вникать